# JavaScript image preloading and 403 error

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-403

I'm preloading Images using Javascript. Some of them returns with error.

How can I know in code which error it is?
404/403?
`onerror (evt)` doesn't provide one - or I just don't know where to look.

thanks.

**UPDATE**

I know that I can use FireBug / WebInspector... I need to decide dynamically, via code, which image to put on screen instead of erroneous one: "Image not found" or "Prohibited" or sth.

Answer (score 1):

Install a firebug (mozilla plug-in) and check the net tab. Click on a request and the on response tab.

Comment: Another very useful plugin is [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome also has built in functionality to debug stuff like this - its under tools/developertools